# Is there a Google Playstore alternative?

Tags: android, google-play

I am very new to android programming. I have a personal project which is my first android project. I built an apk using Android Studio and I installed it on my personal phone. It works. However, I often have to make small changes to the app and everytime I need to deploy it on my mobile, I have to build apk, copy the apk to my phone via USB connection, open my file manager on mobile and install the apk.

I checked Google Playstore. There is a $25 sign up fee and the whole process to get an account created. Since this is just for me to install it on my one or two phones, I don't feel worth to go through the hassle of setting up a developer account at Google Playstore. Is there an alternative service where I can host the apk (I can also host it on my personal site publicly) and auto-upgrade the app on my phone when I release a new version? I also want to make sure that only I have the access to download the app from this store.

I came across a few sites such as APKMirror, APKPure etc. I am not sure if those would be a fit for my case. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build an apk, use **Run 'app'** in your android studio

here is the link [Connect to your device using USB](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)

Comment: If I do that it wouldn't create the icon on the launcher right ? On top of that, I need to keep the USB Debugging enabled. I use the phone for Outlook for my work and they use Intune Company Portal which will stop working if I keep the USB Debugging enabled as it will flag as a non-compliance phone

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

you can check **[Amazon App Store](https://developer.amazon.com/apps-and-games)**. also [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution) distribution also fit in your case.